# How to fix this issue ? FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, mobile-development

I try to add a package name as new_version: ^0.2.3. After the terminal return the below error. How can I fix this?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Build file 'D:\User\Projects\Flutter\apptech_beta-master.android\Flutter\build.gradle' line: 33

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter'.

> Could not get unknown property 'compileSdkVersion' for extension 'flutter' of type FlutterExtension.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

This is the build.gradle file

exception: Gradle task assembleStagingDebug failed with exit code 1

```
    def flutterPluginVersion = 'managed'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.app"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2.1"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "flavor"

    productFlavors {
        staging {
            dimension "flavor"
        }
    }


}
buildDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "../build/host")
dependencies {
    implementation project(':flutter')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue and fixed it by modifying the **format** of file `key.properties`.
You can try to comment on the following line (and the following `signingConfigs`) to see if the build is success:

> // keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

You can also reference the file `local.properties` for what the correct format of the properties file should be (path should be 2 `\`, no quotes...)

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=2
```